# AWS Session Expires After Downloading from S3 Web UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-s3

I can browse S3 fine, but as soon as I perform a single download from S3 web UI my session expires. Trying to perform another download I get:

```
An error occurred generating the download link for "FILENAME.TXT"
Try downloading these objects again.
```

Trying again does nothing. If I navigate to a different bucket I get this warning:

```
Please sign in again
Your session has expired. Please reload the page and reauthenticate.
```

A browser refresh (F5) solves warning, and an "auto-refresh" extension works, but these make the web interaction painful.

It seems there's some issue here as I can't believe this is their UX Design choice.

Comment: Actually, I could believe this is Amazon's UX decision as it sounds like their anti-pattern to get me to use the CLI.